# How do i pass data around between 2 widget methods within the same file and rebuild a section instead of push/pushreplacement in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

so im working on an app and come across a situation which I need to work around and cant really seem to find how to. Ive seperated my widgets into seperate build classes/methods and added them in my main Material build element within my `MainFoster_screen.dart`. `petOptions.dart` is a scroll list with different avaialable animal types. I need to pass the index of the chosen animal category to `petView.dart` and display pets available based on the selected category. 1. How do i send the selected category to the `petView` function. 2. Without sending a push to replace the page (as i want to just rebuild the lower section and update the available pets).

MainFoster_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../widgets/petOptions.dart';
import '../widgets/petView.dart';
import '../models/animals.dart';
import '../dummy_data.dart';

class Main_Foster extends StatefulWidget {
  int PetIconIndex = 0;

  static const routeName = "/mainFoster";
  @override
  State<Main_Foster> createState() => _Main_FosterState();
}

class _Main_FosterState extends State<Main_Foster> {
  bool isFavorite = false;

  void _Favorite() {
    setState(() {
      isFavorite = !isFavorite;
    });
  }

  Color greyColor = Color.fromRGBO(245, 245, 245, 1);

  //**********Main UI ****/
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      color: Color.fromRGBO(245, 245, 245, 1),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 60.0,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            //Appbar Widget
            appBar(),
            Expanded(
              //main background Widget
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      //Search Bar
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                            vertical: 20, horizontal: 18),
                        child: Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(245, 245, 245, 1),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14)),
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 12),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.search,
                                color: Colors.grey,
                                size: 18,
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                child: TextField(
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                          left: 8,
                                          bottom: 11,
                                          top: 12,
                                          right: 15),
                                      hintText: "Search for a new companion"),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 14,
                                      color: Color.fromRGBO(182, 182, 182, 1)),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      //Icon Buttons
                      petOptions(),
                      //Available pets widget
                      petView(),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

petView.dart

```
class petView extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/petViewW';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: animals.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return InkWell(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 330,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          colors: [
                            Color.fromRGBO(188, 233, 255, 1),
                            Color.fromRGBO(160, 160, 255, 1),
                          ]),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(182, 182, 182, 0.5),
                          offset: Offset(0, 0),
                          blurRadius: 3,
                          spreadRadius: 1,
                        )
                      ],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  animals[index].name,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 28,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 1,
                                ),
                                Text(animals[index].animal_Breed),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 5,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    InkWell(
                                      onTap: () => {},
                                      child: Icon(
                                        FontAwesomeIcons.heart,
                                        size: 14,
                                        color: Colors.red,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Expanded(
                            flex: 1,
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                              child: Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                child: Image(
                                  height: 250,
                                  width: 240,
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  image: AssetImage(animals[index].Image),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                        child: Row(
                          children: [
                            Expanded(
                              flex: 1, // 60%
                              child: ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(15),
                                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15)),
                                child: Container(
                                  height: 65,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                    children: [
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Icon(
                                            animals[index].isMale
                                                ? FontAwesomeIcons.mars
                                                : FontAwesomeIcons.venus,
                                            size: 23,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            animals[index].isMale
                                                ? "Male"
                                                : "Female",
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Icon(
                                            FontAwesomeIcons.clock,
                                            size: 20,
                                            color: Colors.grey,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: 6,
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                            "${animals[index].age}" + " Years",
                                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

petOptions.dart

```
class petOptions extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _petOptions createState() => _petOptions();
}

class _petOptions extends State<petOptions> {
  var selectedPetIcon = 0;

  var selectedAnimalCategory = '0';
  void selectAnimal(BuildContext context, int index) {
    selectedPetIcon = index;
  }

  //Pet icon button creation
  Widget createPetIcons(
      BuildContext context, int index, String id, String name, String image) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        right: 30.0,
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          //Change Selected on tap
          InkWell(
            onTap: () => setState(() {
              selectAnimal(context, index);
            }),
            //Icon main box
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: selectedPetIcon == index
                      ? Color.fromRGBO(255, 211, 211, 1)
                      : Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(182, 182, 182, 0.5),
                      offset: Offset(0, 1),
                      blurRadius: 3,
                      spreadRadius: 1,
                    )
                  ],
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              //Icon
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                child: Center(
                  child: ImageIcon(
                    AssetImage(image),
                    color: selectedPetIcon == index
                        ? Colors.black
                        : Color.fromRGBO(182, 182, 182, 1),
                    size: 35,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 12,
          ),
          //Icon Text
          Text(
            name,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: selectedPetIcon == index
                    ? Colors.black
                    : Color.fromRGBO(182, 182, 182, 1),
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 110,
          child: ListView.builder(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18, top: 4),
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: animalCategories.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return createPetIcons(
                    context,
                    index,
                    animalCategories[index].id,
                    animalCategories[index].name,
                    animalCategories[index].Image);
              }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

animals.dart (Holds Animals available)

```
//Creating new class to assign and initiate values to new animals
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Animal {
  final String id;
  final String category;
  String name;
  String animal_Breed;
  String Scientific_Name;
  double age;
  bool isMale;
  String Image;

  Animal(
      {required this.id,
      required this.category,
      required this.name,
      required this.animal_Breed,
      required this.Scientific_Name,
      required this.age,
      required this.Image,
      required this.isMale});
}
```

animalCategories.dart (Holds categories)

```
//Creating new class to assign and initiate values to new animals
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AnimalCategories {
  final String id;
  String name;

  String Image;

  AnimalCategories({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.Image,
  });
}
```

Comment: check https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-ZG-jS5QHQ

Comment: Oh Great! ValueListenableBuilder works so well! Thanks so much!

Comment: sure, your welcome